# How to search the date format 20180603 present inside a file using java?

Tags: java, date, filereader

I have a file in which the words are delimited by "|". Here I need to search the date "20180603". However, I can't hardcode the value to be search. The date format is fixed YYYYDDMM and the date can be anything. 
I need to convert the date present here to today's date (system date).

I am pasting how the external file looks (only I have added asterisks around the relevant values for emphasis):

```
00000548|WILLIAM|HUBER|WH5718||N|**20180306**|SVP-TECHNICAL FIELD SERVICES|06|329000.00 |0.00 |0.00 |205440.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |55000.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |1600.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |225502.08 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |27629.91 |36717.17 |0.00 |33.000 |0.000 |F
00000828|NORBERTA|NOGUERA|NN1413||N|**20180306**|VP-SPECIAL PROJECTS|05|213000.00 |0.00 |88464.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |86502.87 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |16811.41 |15023.40 |0.00 |33.000 |0.000 |F
00001308|ERROL|PHIPPS|EP4499||N|00000548|WILLIAM|HUBER|WH5718||N|20180306|SVP-TECHNICAL FIELD SERVICES|06|329000.00 |0.00 |0.00 |205440.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |55000.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |1600.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |225502.08 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |27629.91 |36717.17 |0.00 |33.000 |0.000 |F
00000828|NORBERTA|NOGUERA|NN1413||N|**20180306**|VP-SPECIAL PROJECTS|05|213000.00 |0.00 |88464.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |86502.87 |0.00 |0.00 |0.00 |16811.41 |15023.40 |0.00 |33.000 |0.000 |F
00001308|ERROL|PHIPPS|EP4499||N|**20180306**|VP-LEGAL BUSINESS HEAD|05|241000.00 |0.00 |94365.00 |0.00 |0.00 ||VP-LEGAL BUSINESS HEAD|05|241000.00 |0.00 |94365.00 |0.00 |0.00 |
```

I have tried many questions but with no luck.

Below is the code I tried;

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f1= new File("C:/Users/kumar.sushobhan/Desktop/ESPYTR_Big_file_EXEC.dat");
        //File f1= new File("C:/Users/kumar.sushobhan/Desktop/h.txt");
        String words[]= null;
        FileReader fr= new FileReader(f1);
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);

        String s;
        int c = 0;

        String regex= "\\d{4}\\d{2}\\d{2}";
        while((s= br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            words= s.split("|");
            for(String word: words)
            {
                //System.out.println(word);
                if(word.equals(regex))
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(c);
        fr.close();
    }

}
```

I am expecting the date present in snapshot to be read and changed into current system date.

Comment: It's always the 7th column? If so, `words[6]` is where it is. No need for regex (and you aren't using them correctly anyway)

Comment: Please post an example of a single line in file `ESPYTR_Big_file_EXEC.dat`. Is it a plain text file? The conventional suffix for a text file on Windows is `.txt` and not `.dat` The latter suffix is usually for binary data files.

Comment: Its a dat file... I have pasted the content here...

Comment: @SeanBright - Yes its always the 7th column. Can you please help me out here, how you are reading the words[6] and comparing and then changing?

Comment: I believe that if you got your regular expression solution to work, it would catch `00000548` too. So if this isn’t a date, I suggest you add a range check.

Comment: `YYYYDDMM` is very unusual for a date format (20180306 for 3 June 2018). Please check once more if it shouldn’t be `YYYYMMDD` (so 20180306 for March 6, 2018), which is standard.

Comment: The 7th column of the 3rd record is not a date, so it must not always be the 7th column.

Comment: @SeanBright It seems to me that some cells from the first line have been erroneously copied to the place that you mention, so in the real data this may not be an issue. In any case one should of course validate that there are at least 7 columns and that the 7th column contains a date in some appropriate date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic algorithm that will look in a pipe delimited file, replacing values that "look like" a date with the current date, and then write everything back out to a new file. It uses `YYYYDDMM` format that you describe in your question, but it should probably be `YYYYMMDD` and I've noted where you would need to make changes. This cuts a few corners with date validation and error handling to try and keep it relatively short, but I've over-commented to try and explain everything:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DateReplacer
{
    private static final Pattern DATE_MATCHER =
            Pattern.compile("(?:(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})");

    public static void main(String... args)
            throws Exception
    {
        // These are the paths to our input and output files
        Path input = Paths.get("input.dat");
        Path output = Paths.get("output.dat");

        // We need to get today's date in YYYYDDMM format, so we create a
        // DateFormatter for that. If it turns out that your date format is
        // actually YYYYMMDD, you can just use DateFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE
        // instead.
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyddMM");
        String todaysDate = LocalDate.now().format(formatter);

        // Use try-with-resources to create a reader & writer
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(input);
             BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(output)) {
            String line;

            // Read lines until there are no more lines
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Split them on the | character, notice that it needs to be
                // escaped because it is a regex metacharacter
                String[] columns = line.split("\\|");

                // Iterate over every column...
                for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                    // ... and if the value looks like a date ...
                    if (isDateLike(columns[i])) {
                        // ... overwrite with today's date.
                        columns[i] = todaysDate;
                    }
                }

                // Re-join the columns with the | character and write it out
                writer.write(String.join("|", columns));
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isDateLike(String str)
    {
        // Avoid the regular expression if we can
        if (str.length() != 8) {
            return false;
        }

        Matcher matcher = DATE_MATCHER.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            // If it turns out that your date format is actually YYYYMMDD
            // you will need to swap these two lines.
            int day = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1), 10);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2), 10);

            // We don't need to validate year because we already know
            // it is between 1900 and 2099 inclusive
            return day >= 1 && day <= 31 && month >= 1 && month <= 12;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This example uses [a `try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that the input and output files are properly closed.

Comment: This works like charm and this is what exactly I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Basically a fine answer, thanks. I see no point in using `ZonedDateTime` here. Wouldn’t `LocalDate` be a better fit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like following.

```
  String regex = "(19|20)[0-9][0-9](0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30|31)";
```

It is not perfect but it will match to most dates. For example, it will eliminate dates that have a month beyond 12. Also, it will work for dates till the year 2099. It does not take care of date rules like June having 30 days. It will match to any date having days between 1-31.

You can not use `equals` for date. You will have to use `Pattern.matches(regex, string)`